# Eclipse Juno SR2 and Subclipse with Maven

Tags: eclipse, svn, maven-3, subclipse

I'm working on getting my team moved over to Eclipse Juno SR2 and we're currently running Subversion (1.6 server). We're getting the native linux client as well shortly to get us up to client 1.7. I'm seeing some inconsistent behavior with regard to svn:ignore properties.

Currently I've got a multi-module maven project setup (I've got latest version of integrations etc for maven, spring, and other tools). The projects in SVN each have the following svn:ignore property

```
.project
.classpath
.settings
.springBeans
target
```

For whatever reason, under Juno with Subclipse 1.8 running the SVNKit client adapter I'm seeing changes showing up under ${project_loc}/.settings and some of the files under target are showing up as "new".

Does anyone have suggestions or ideas? Is this a bug?

Also please PLEASE do not comment that "git, hg, bob's vcs is better than svn, you should switch". I've had that argument over and over and over and I've been shot down continually.

Comment: what is the behaviour if you mark those resources as ignored in window > preferences > team > ignored resources ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug.  Currently being fixed and should be rolled out next week.  If you can rollback your JavaHL or SVNKit plugins to the previous 1.7.8.1 version that will also temporarily resolve it.

Comment: can you clarify on this - SVNKit plugins? the only available svnkit libraries I see are 1.7.8.r9538_v20130107_2001 and 1.7.5.v1_r9382_v20120718_1415 from http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x is that correct?

Comment: The SVNKit library itself is fine.  I was referring to the SVNKit client adapter.  You would need to get the old version out of the archive for the 1.8.18 release. http://subclipse.tigris.org/archive/   You should keep the current version of the SVNKit library.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - also HUGE to know about that archive